# How to get the success/fail build information in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to execute shell script if build is success and execute other script if it fails, is there any plugin or shell script to get build success/failure?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the Jenkinsfile, it lets you write custom failure handler using Groovy :  https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples

Answer (score 3):

You can write a Groovy pipiline with this structure:

```
node {
//Define your variables (if you need)

    stage('First stage') {
       try {
           //Your code
       } catch (Exception err) {
           currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
       }
    }

    stage('Last stage') {
         try {
           //Your code
        } catch (Exception err) {
           currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        }
     }

     echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
}
```

Second, thirty... stages only will be executed if previusly steeps builds correctly.

If all your stages build correctly, the status in Jenkins will be `SUCCESS` but if anyone fails the status will be `FAILURE`.

Answer (score 0):

no plugins necessary use the jenkins `post` block after your `stages` block

```
post {

  always {
    echo "I'm always ran"
  }

  success {
    echo "All builds completed OK"
  }

  failure {
    echo "A job failed"

  }
}
```

documentation on this can be found here:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post